# normalize ggplot histogram so that first height is 1 (to show growth) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, normalization, histogram

I was wondering if there is a way to normalize the heights of the histograms with multiple groups so that their first heights are all = 1. For instance:

```
results <- rep(c(1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,4,4,2,5,7),3)
category <- rep(c("a","b","c"),15)
data <- data.frame(results,category)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=results, fill = category, y = ..count..))
p + geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

gives a regular histogram with 3 groups.
Also

```
results <- rep(c(1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,4,4,2,5,7),3)
category <- rep(c("a","b","c"),15)
data <- data.frame(results,category)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=results, fill = category, y = ..ncount..))
p + geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

gives a the histogram where each group is normalized to have maximum height of 1.
I want to get a histogram where each group is normalized to have first height of 1 (so I can show growth) but I don't understand if there is an appropriate alternative to ..ncount or ..count.. or if anyone can help me understand the structure of ..count.. I could maybe figure it out from there. 
Thanks!

Comment: +1 for reproducible example showing what you tried and why it didn't work. Great first question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet there is a nice way to do everything within `ggplot`. However, I tend to prefer preparing the desired data set before I plug it into `ggplot`. If I understood you correctly, you may try something like this:

```
# convert 'results' to factor and set levels to get an equi-spaced 'results' x-axis
df$results <- factor(df$results, levels = 1:7)

# for each category, count frequency of 'results' 
df <- as.data.frame(with(df, table(results, category)))

# normalize: for each category, divide all 'Freq' (heights) with the first 'Freq'
df$freq2 <- with(df, ave(Freq, category, FUN = function(x) x/x[1]))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = results, y = freq2, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking to do. It would be to know though if there is a way of having this automated in ggplot bc to me this seems like it should be a common enough question, but this is seems like a very clear and useful solution. THANKS!

Comment: Sounds like in general you'd want to also change the one line to `
df$freq2 <- with(df, ave(Freq, category, FUN = function(x) x/max(x)))`, in case the first element isn't the maximum.

Comment: @JLLagrange, Thanks for your comment. As I understood the question, the values should be normalized against the _first_ height ("each group is normalized to have first height of 1"), not the maximum height.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question, again.  You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `..density..` does what you want, but I can't for the life of me find documentation on it.  On both your examples it does what you are looking for, though!

```
results <- rep(c(1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,4,4,2,5,7),3)
category <- rep(c("a","b","c"),15)
data <- data.frame(results,category)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=results, fill = category, y = ..density..))
p + geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to give exactly what I am looking for. the first heights I get when I enter that are 2 for 'a', 2 for 'b' and '1' for 'c.
what I do get though is a graph where the total areas for each category is equal to 1. (their base widths are set to range/30 which is 1/5 here). 
thanks though!